# JS Add folder to favorite web sites

Tags: javascript

How can I add folder to favorite web sites by js or other scripts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't manipulate the state of your browser with JavaScript, only very few important actions are allowed (like cookies etc).

Comment: as luca mentioned this is not possible on the programmers ways.
but you can try to give the user some kind of step by step guidance and mostly he will follow them ;-)